# About the relation of rank(AB), rank(A), rank(B) and the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 4$ matrix and $B$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix, prove that if $rank(A) = 2$ and $rank(B)=3$ then $AB \neq 0$.

I got stuck at $rank(AB) \leq 2 $

How do I continue from here?

Comment: the inequality is in the wrong direction, it conspires against us. try thinking about finding a vector that $AB$ doesn't send to zero, using the ranks of the individual matrices

Comment: with the given matrices size the product $AB$ hasn't a sens.

Comment: Right its $2 x 4$ for A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that,

$rank (AB)=rank (B)-\dim(Img(B)\cap Ker A)$

Reason: Take the Vector Space $Img(B)$ .Let T be a linear transformation on $Img(B)$ represented by the matrix $A$

Then by rank -nullity theorem we have,

$rank (T)+dim(Ker(T))=m$ where m is the dimension of $Img (B)$ and this is equal to $rank (B)$.

Now we have $rank (AB)=rank (T)$ and $Ker (T)=\{v\in Img (B)|Av=0\}=\{v\in Img (B)|v\in Ker (A)\}=Img (B)\cap Ker (A)$.

From this $rank (AB)=rank (B)-\dim(Img(B)\cap Ker A)$ follows.

Now we have in case of this problem

$\dim(Ker (A))=2$(Reason :$\dim(Ker (A))+rank (A)=4$ and as $rank (A)=2$)

$\Rightarrow \dim(Img(B)\cap Ker A) \leq \dim(Ker (A))=2$

$rank (AB)=rank (B)-\dim(Img(B)\cap Ker A) \geq 3-2 = 1$

So $AB\ne 0$

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments your matrix $A$ is the wrong way round... As, for our purposes, is the inequality! (It's right, just not helpful since what we want is $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\ge1$.)

Here's an equivalent way of saying $AB=0$.

> The image of $B$ is entirely contained within the kernel of $A$.

Can you see why this can't happen?

Comment: to be fair, Sharkos and i simply mean that the inequality is the wrong way around *for this problem*. it is, of course, true :)

Comment: Good point, I should rephrase that!

Comment: The image of $B$ can not be entirely contained within the kernel of $A$ becase $dim(ImB) > dim(KerA)$?

Comment: Indeed! That suffices.